# Swift 2 unused constant warning

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constants, swift2

I am getting a warning saying my constant is unused:

> Initialization of immutable value 'myConst' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

```
if someVal["value"] != nil {
    let myConst = someVal["value"]
}
```

So what will renaming `let myConst = someVal["value"]` into `_ myConst = someVal["value"]` do/mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're not replacing let with `_`, but you're replacing the variable name with it.  If the variable isn't used anywhere in the code it's irrelevant so the line can be written like:

```
_ = someVal["value"]
```

If you want to use it somewhere you need a name for it to reference it later on.  But when you don't use it writing `_` is a lot easier ...

Comment: why we use declare object in another object???if we dont want to use the its give warning why?is this bug of sift language?? i need only this one line let stingname : String = objectfile.name but its give me warning why??if i am using in print statement then its not give any warning.....why??

Answer (score 1):

we can use **Wildcard Pattern ' _ '** for unused constant warings

Answer (score 0):

If you are never using it there is no need for the compiler to use `let/var variable_name`.
So do not replace it with `_` if you mean to use it later.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this suggestion was planning for 'if let' statements and similar. Probably will be removed for useless statements on future updates.