# cs193p calculator: why doesn't it let me declare a property? here's the simple code

Tags: swift, calculator, cs193p

[cs193p]  Swift calculator: why doesn't it let me declare a property? here's the simple code...

i am on swift 1.2

the error is: 
initialization of variable ‘digit’ was never used ; consider replacing with assignment to ‘_'
or removing it

here's the code

(it doesn't like the 'let digit'... 'var digit' gets same error)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        //initialization of immutable value digit...
        let digit = sender.currentTitle//<-- doesnt like this!!!!!!

    }

}
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear about what the problem is: you're initializating the constant "digit" and never using it. So use it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift is designed as very safe language. Among others compiler checks if variables/constants you declared are used - so as stated in comments by Aurast, just use it.

If you wandering, what replacing by "_" would mean, check this question: [Swift 2 unused constant warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705070/swift-2-unused-constant-warning)

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a ***warning***, not an ***error*** and what it's complaining about is that you never used `digit` after initializing it. So down the line and it'll go away.

Simplest way to silence the warning:

Swift **1.2:** `println("current digit is: \(digit)")`

Swift **2:** `print("current digit is: \(digit)")`